# Retaining value commas but removing separator commas in arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Hopefully I'm wording this correctly.

I have an Array:

```
var thisArray = ["This","That","This and That","This, That or Something Else"];
```

And what I want to do is convert this to a string, and when converted, replace all the comma separators from break tags, BUT preserve the commas inside each value.

Right now, I have this block of code:

```
var thisArray = ["This","That","This and That","This, That or Something Else"];
var thisString = thisArray.toString();
var thisResult = thisString.replace(",","<br/>");
return thisResult;
```

But of course, this way, would net me an actual result of:

```
This
That
This and That
This
That or Something Else
```

When I want the result to be

```
This
That
This and That
This, That or Something Else
```

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: Use the [`.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)  -> `thisArray.join('<br />')`

Comment: @hindmost replace on an array? not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join an array using anything as a separator:

```
return thisArray.join('<br />')
```

Comment: My pleasure, but pretty sure @Josh Crozier answered (commented) first :)